# How to rename files in the folder output report (robotframework, ride)

Tags: python, testing, automation, robotframework

When I have a few test cases, generates the output folder files to me:
For testing I use robotframework and pycharm

```
log.html
output.xml
report.xml
```

After each test, the files are overwritten.
Is there a possibility that the names of these files after the match in my tests, so I do not have to change their names or create separate folders for each test - for example:

```
log_test1.html
output_test1.xml
report_test1.xml
```

Whether to use some parameters that will take me the name of the test and passed it on to the name of the output file?

Please help how can I set this up using pycharm

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

All Robot Framework output files can be automatically timestamped with the option --timestampoutputs:

```
pybot --timestampoutputs tests.html
```

See User Guide section ["Timestamping output files"](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#timestamping-output-files)